# The flash keeps flickering onmouseover, jquery

Tags: jquery

Hey there, I have this code... when i mouseover the flash feed  it flickers and reloads, why? Thank you;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#test").mouseover(function() {
 $("#test").html('`<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="250" height="250"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="250" height="250" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>`');
});


$("#test").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#test").html('ddd');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) which fires when entering the child element as well, use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), like this:

```
$("#test").mouseenter(function() {
 $(this).html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="250" height="250"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="250" height="250" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>');
});
```

From [the `.mouseenter()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/):

> The `mouseenter` event differs from `mouseover` in the way it handles event bubbling. If `mouseover` were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved over the **Inner** element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The `mouseenter` event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse enters the **Outer** element, but not the **Inner** element.

You could also narrow this down using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), like this:

```
$("#test").hover(function() {
  $(this).html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="250" height="250"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="250" height="250" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>');
}, function() {
  $(this).html('ddd');
});
```